# Bluetooth communication in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i'm writing an application for bluetooth comunication for Win7 desktop PC(VB.net) in visual studio 2012, i need to send a string over bluetooth to another device, actually i'm using a Bluegiga bluetooth low energy device that is identified by my PC as 
[COM4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv5Xp.png)

It's the first time that i work with bluetooth, someone can give me a little tip? i suppose that i need to use serial protocol, am i wrong?
Also i can't detect my low energy device with my android smartphone with low energy scanner, what i have to do?

Comment: You can use the [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) class to send data through the serial port, there are examples of how to do that on the documentation page.

Comment: Ok but i think that i need to connect the bluetooths before to write something in serial and i can't find the device attached to my pc, i tried to find it with android phone, laptop, another phone, I have to assume that the key is the problem?

Comment: Your computer handles creating the bluetooth connection pairing, once it's connected then you use the SerialPort class to open the port and write data to it